# How much RAM samsung devices do normally allocate for Android apps?

Tags: java, android, memory, out-of-memory, ram

[image: Flurry statistics]

Now my app has 2000 downloads and 180 daily users. I don't believe they all use Samsung devices only. I am confused - I don't have any samsung devices, please if you have one - could you please tell me how much RAM they normally allocate for android application? My app normally consumes 20-22mb +2mb per UI reload as memory leaks (but users normally don't do this more than 2-3 times so...)
I have added "LargeHeap" in last version (not in statistics yet).

Is this 46 OutOfMemory errors a lot for 14500 sessions? Or it is okay for android?

Comment: You've got a 2MB memory leak and you're wondering about memory allocation on a specific brand? Wrong priorities, mate.

Comment: Well its just weather app. People don't normally watch weather at more than one location (so in the most cases it happens only once). There are a lot of imageViews in app and to do all of them in proper way is quite troublesome.

Comment: "There are a lot of imageViews in app and to do all of them in proper way is quite troublesome." -- Subclass them if you're too lazy to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the wrong question. You should be trying to figure out how to make your application less memory-hungry, not trying to find workarounds for specific vendors/OEMs.

For some guidance, this article is particularly helpful: [Managing Your App's Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html). Since you mentioned that you are attempting to use the `largeHeap` attribute in your manifest, you might want to read the following snippet from the article:

> In very special situations, you can request a larger heap size by setting the `largeHeap` attribute to `"true"` in the manifest `<application>` tag. If you do so, you can call `getLargeMemoryClass()` to get an estimate of the large heap size.
>
> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such as a large photo editing app). **Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix**.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not something I can fix fast. I ll sure deal with this later.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was down voted twice, but I'm not going to stick with my answer because I think that this is the right approach. The OP should not be using `largeHeap` as a workaround and should not need to know the specific amount of memory Samsung devices use in order to implement a working application. Doing so is not guaranteed to work for all devices and is generally bad practice.

Comment: Well, untill today I was sure that android 4.0+ devices allocate at least 50mb of RAM. If I dont know how much RAM my app can use, then I don't know which Images can I use in it. I understand that leaks are bad. I am the one who voted up, not down.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is full of drive-by downvoters these days. :/

Comment: @careful7j Have you looked at [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) about caching/displaying bitmaps properly? Displaying image views usually doesn't require knowing the size of the heap... instead, it requires knowing how to cache bitmaps, how to scale them down to a less memory-consuming size, how to recycle them when they are no longer in use, etc. It is a tricky subject because mobile devices don't tend to have that much memory... but there are a ton of articles online that you'll probably find helpful.

Comment: Yes I will definetly try to fix this. This article says I have to use less than 16mb and it refers to android 2.1 (lol). I'am interested how much memory can I use today, to support 4.0+ devices. To reduce the quality of images just because they are greedy for memory (while most devices have 1GB or more) is not something I should do, i believe. However my question is still unanswered. Don't you have samsung devices?